# How to change design of checkout billing in Magento 1.9.1?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, php

I have copied the file ../template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml to my theme and I have changed its code, but nothing changes. Other files like shipping changes when I make a modification.

Why does this happen? How can I change the billing.phtml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out particular template file in magento, use template hint paths. here is the good tutorial to enable this:

`http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-template-path-hints-magento`

You can access Checkout billing step file from the following location in your theme:

`template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

Hope this helps !!